# Error code numbers. Define proper values

Tags: bash, debian

I saw

```
E_NOTROOT=87   # Non-root exit error
```

in the one of the bash script examples. Where this value was taken from? How can I find proper error numbers for such kind of errors in bash environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not amongst the official GNU libc or linux error codes ([1](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html), [2](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-0.99/S/35.html))

I assume you are just playing with some code examples from [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html).

I believe the author just built its own error code *(with a value high enough not to interact with the existing ones!)* to use it in case the user id (stored in the bash internal variable [`$UID`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)) is not equal to the root user id (`$UID` is 0 for root).

Comment: It isn't in [sysexits.h](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+4.3-RELEASE&format=html) either.